# Collect signal values to an array using ReactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I use ReactiveCocoa to record the taps in an array:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *first10Taps;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  RACSignal *tapSignal = [[self.tapGesture rac_gestureSignal] map:^id(UITapGestureRecognizer *sender) {
    return [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[sender locationInView:sender.view]];
  }];

  // This signal will send the first 10 tapping positions and then send completed signal.
  RACSignal *first10TapSignal = [tapSignal take:10];

  // Need to turn this signal to a sequence with the first 10 taps.
  RAC(self, first10Taps) = [first10TapSignal ...];
}
@end
```

How to turn this signal to an array signal?

I need to update the array every time a new value is sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for Michał Ciuba's answer. Using `-collect` will only send the collection value when the upstream signal is completed.

I found the way using `-scanWithStart:reduce:` to produce a signal which will send the collection every time a `next` value is sent.

```
RAC(self, first10Taps) = [firstTapSetSignal scanWithStart:[NSMutableArray array]  reduce:^id(NSMutableArray *collectedValues, id next) {
  [collectedValues addObject:(next ?: NSNull.null)];
  return collectedValues;
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a method on `RACSignal` called, well, `collect`. Its documentation says:

> Collects all receiver's `next`s into a NSArray. Nil values will be
>   converted to NSNull. This corresponds to the `ToArray` method in Rx.
>   Returns a signal which sends a single NSArray when the receiver
>   completes successfully.

So you can simply use:

```
RAC(self, first10Taps) = [first10TapSignal collect];
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. Is that possible sending the values every time it updates? Using `collect` only sends the values when it completes. I need to reload the table view every time a new value received.